# bootstrap 2 modal load image dynamically

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, load, modal-dialog

I'm trying to load dynamically an image on a bootstrap3 modal.

[See that in action.](http://www.hostivate.com/blog/how-to-add-qtranslate-support-on-woocommerce-categories/)

When I first click on the thumbnail I get the source code of the image.
When I close the modal and click the thumbnail again it works fine.

My jQuery code:

```
jQuery('.featuredimglink').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.modal-body').empty();
    var title = jQuery(this).attr("title");
    jQuery('h3.modal-title').html(title);
    var img = (jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src')).replace('-150x150', '');
    jQuery('.modal-body').html('<img src="'+ img +'" alt="'+ title +'" />');
    jQuery('#myModal').modal({show:true});
});
```

My modal code:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can also see that

```
jQuery('#myModal').modal({show:true});
```

fires an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal'

---

**RESOLVED**

Just initializing the modal before the click function. Here is my final code:

```
  var mymodal = jQuery('#myModal').modal({
    show: false
  });

  jQuery('.featuredimglink').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('.modal-body').empty();
    var title = jQuery(this).attr("title");
    jQuery('h3.modal-title').html(title);
    var img = (jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src')).replace('-150x150', '');
    jQuery('.modal-body').html('<img src="'+ img +'" alt="'+ title +'" />');
    mymodal.modal('show');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap for the modal dialog, you need to reference the bootstrap css and the bootstrap js file.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then replace

```
jQuery('#myModal').modal({show:true});
```

with

```
jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it's bootstrap 2 and jQuery and Bootstrap are included, js and css files.